# How do I create a tickbox that deletes all the cells in a row in google sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets, scripting

I would like to create a tick bot here : [image]

So what it does is if I select the tick on for exemple the first row, it just deletes all the data on that row (and leaving the timestamp as it is, just deleting all the data for exemple the 5 / 454 / 54 / 54)

Because what I want to do is for exemple as you can see some cells are blank, and I don't want to count the entire row if one of the cells inside that row is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to use an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger that will:

1. Check the cell is a cell with a checkbox (based on row and column number).
2. Verify the checkbox is set to `TRUE`, by the cell's value.
3. If applicable, obtain all the data using `getRange()`, `getValues()`. Remove the unnecessary data and set the data back into the sheet, using `setValues()`.

Below you can see an example of how your trigger would look like:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var row = e.range.getRow();

  // Check cell position is right, and checkbox has been set to true (enabled)
  if (row > 1 && col == 10 && e.value === 'TRUE') {
    var rangeToClear = e.range.getSheet().getRange(row, 1, 1, 10);
    var valuesToClear = rangeToClear.getValues();
    for (var i=1; i<8; i++) {
      valuesToClear[0][i] = '';
    }

    // Uncheck checkbox
    valuesToClear[0][9] = 'FALSE';

    // Set cleared row back into sheets
    rangeToClear.setValues(valuesToClear);
  }
}
```